# How do I cut in half a complex drawing in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, illustration, drawing, pathfinder

I have drawn two faces for a logo in Adobe Illustrator and I want to cut them in half so I can put text in the middle. This is how I want it to look:

> [image]

Currently, I have these two faces:

> [image]

It's not working when I try Pathfinder with a shape in front of the 2 images, it gives me weird results. Also using the knife or scissors won't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Illustrator's **Clipping Masks** would work....

Draw a rectangle on top of each face which covers the area you *want to show*.

[image]

Select the face and the rectangle and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`.

Then repeat for the other face.

[image]

This won't "cut" the faces, but it will *hide* the portions which are outside the rectangle(s).

---

If you then want to actually *cut and remove* the hidden portions of the faces, do the above and then select one face and choose `Object > Expand` (if available) and then hit the `Crop` button on the **Pathfinder Panel**, repeat for second face.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be to space your faces where you want them and add a white filled rectangle to cover the half faces.  Then add your text over that.

Comment: That was what i did for the example, but it wouldn't work when using the logo on a non-white background.